Як правильно позначається українська "и" в МФА?
На Вікіпедії написано, що українська "и" це [ɪ], прослуховуючи запис цього звуку, я лише чую щось на кшталт "і". Деякі інші джерела стверджують, що "и" може бути [ɨ], хоча це російська вимова "ы". Я лише погоджуюсь, що положення язика при вимові української "и" та [ɪ] подібне, але звуки різні. Я не дуже розбираюсь у фонетиці, тому можуть бути неточності.

Вам треба мати на увазї декілька речей, що повязані зі звуком і буквою и.

чую щось на кшталт і

І це цїлком може бути, бо і може мати в собі вимову:

Волостне, саму і. В стандартній мові зазвичай півпомякшує попереднього приголосного, хоча добра частина діалектів знають про «чисте» і, тобто котре так не робе.
Також частка діалектів знають, де відбулася зміна і → и, таке було і в стандартній вимові — найпоказовіший приклад це дієслівне закінчення -ти, що походить від прасловянського *-ti. Можна також згадати паралельність форм ві відмінках, наприклад в стандартній це родовий відмінок третьої віміни: [немає] солї або соли.

На початку слова як и: інший, іноді, інде, істик, іскра, іграшка, ірод, іч.

Як ьи, якщо наявнии̑ відповідник з и: синій → синь-ий (червон-ий).


Сюди же, очевидно, підпадає також ї: У-край-ина (дол-ина), їх → й-их (н-их). Про це все зазначають чимало джерел. Зазвичай наводять статтю «Ортоепія» від Синявського чи ортоепічний словник Погрїбного.
Від себе би додав, що на місцях чужоземного i теж могла бути двояка вимова, відомі записи через і (втч. ѣ) і и: фіґура, фигура, фѣґура. Зараз це «упорядковано» польським правилом «девятки», але артефакти вимови можуть лишитися і саме те правило має Дізель, але дизель.
Аби було ще веселїше, своєго часу і та ы в більшостї випадків злилися в и. Детальнїше можна прочитати про це наприклад в працї «Історична фонологія української мови» від Шевельова. Там якраз зазначено про точнїші вимови и відносно говірок, наприклад:

28.2 Злиття i та y (ч. перша), стр. 481
Північноукраїнське наріччя відрізняється в цілому переднішою артикуляцією ẏ (yͥ), а в частині говірок (на півночі) y зберігається як ẏ. Відтак, давноукраїнське протиставлення i та y зберігається як yͥ проти y. У частині південно-західних говірок (надсянські, лемківські, бойківські, середньозакарпатські, деякі марамороські) звук *i змінився на ẏ, тимчасом y зберігся незмінним або навіть огублився.

Вище, y — ы, и — ẏ, a yͥ теж и, але переднїший.
Приклади артефактів в сучасній мові: сїд-ниця — сид-їти, дит-ина — дїт-и.
Все ж таки, навіть попри згадані явища, український звук и є окремою фонемою і є чимало чітких пар незалежно від попереднього приголосного і його типу. Коли ж московський ы часто — волостне, це наразї і є домінантною думкою — розглядається як особливий алофон до и, втч. через [майже] відсутність таких пар, оскільки звук и не буває після твердих приголосних — за винятком вже лише твердих приголосних, до котрих пишуть и, але кажуть ы. Як вже знаїмо з вище, и може бути після палаталізованих приголосних, втч. й: й-ім — й-им, синь-ий (називнии̑, пор. червоний) — синь-ій (місцевий, давальний, пор. червоній) ітд; окремо зазначу, ненаголошений є це тупо ненаголошений ї, наприклад сучасний запис її, це старий запис єї (пор. неї); також жодних проблем з приголосними як ц, ж, ш, г і к (ґ): цим — цім, ворожий — ворожій, піший — пішій, кіт — кит, вологий — вологій ітд. Всї слова тут питомі. Коли що, польська має подібні проблеми, але геть на іншому рівнї. Питання чому так не пишемо, це вже питання ортоґрафії, а не фонетики; ну і так, популярна фраза пишемо як чуємо — це омана.

Окремо можна також зазначити, що ненаголошений /и/ — ненаголошений /е/ — ще один переднїй голосний звук — [e] за МФА, тому прикладні слова як мине́ і мене́, на виду́ і наведу повністю тотожні за вимовою, а запис їх зазвичай продиктований суто морфолоґією і етѵмолоґією. Тож в підсумку — жодних ознак, чому и за вимовою має бути подібне до моск*вського ы, котрого через редукцію і зі сполуками інших голосних може тянути в геть інший бік — у, а не е, чого не дуже не сказати про українського и. Так само про польського звука до y, що теж зазвичай позначають як [ɨ], але на відміну від моск*вського є переднїшим, тому декотрі можуть позначати це і як [ɪ] (але це не коректно). Також було би добрим тоном указувати ті деякі джерела, бо зазвичай це досить сумнївні особи. Звістно, декотрі говірки зберегли вимову ы, але треба памятати, що це не відповідник и, що в стандартній українській мові і що є досить поширеною помилкою, бо думка в дусї якщо і це и, тоді и = ы вже відпочатку хибна, бо звуки це не лише про букви, а і про їхню поведїнку в звуковому середовищї. Тому и зазвичай наводять як [ɪ] (або [ɪ̟]), а українська буква i вимова и часто може бути на місцях словянських і, втч. моск*вської и — українське пити, московське пить, польське pić.

правильність — це континуум. я народився в києві, для мене наголошене [и] звучить якраз-таки як [ɨ]. але не у кожній говірці/діалекті/різновиді мови воно так звучить. наприклад, в піснях я чув і вимову [ɪ̟].
але якщо вам треба «золота середина», мабуть найкращим записом буде якраз-таки /ɪ/
